# Jquery .closest is undefined

Tags: jquery

This is a part of a bigger application.
What I am trying to do is get the text in `span1` when submitting the form by using `.closest` in Jquery.

The result of `span1 = $(this).closest("span").html()` is undefined though.

**HTML**

```
<span class="span1">
    texthere
</span>
<div>
    <div class="whatever">
        <form id="theform" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="input1" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on("submit","#theform",function(){
    span1 = $(this).closest("span").html();
    input1 = $(this).find("input").val();
    alert(span1+" - "+input1);
    return false;
});
```

[JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QzwMM/)

Why am I getting undefined when reading the `.closest` `.span1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up through the parents (ancestors) of the element and stops on the 1st one that matches your selector.

Your `<form>` is not a child of a `<span>` tag, so `$(this).closest("span")` returns 0 elements.

Answer (score 1):

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

The span is a sibling (of an ancestor) not an ancestor of the form.

Answer (score 0):

in order to find the `closest` `span` you have to make that `span` the parent of the `form`

```
<span>
   <form>
   </form>
</span>
```

You can achieve what you want using the same html you have like this

```
$(document).on("submit","#theform",function(){
    $('.span1').html($('#input1').val());
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/84yKH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
span1 = $(this).parents().filter(function () {
    return $(this).siblings('.span1').length
}).first().siblings('.span1').html();
```